# Ruby DateTime comparison problem

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm implementing a validation method for a model that checks that an expiration date is not before the publication date. I tried with this

```
def valid_date_interval
  if self.expired_at && self.published_at
    errors.add(:published_at, I18n.t('ubiquo.highlight.error_invalid_interval')) if self.expired_at <= self.published_at
  end
end
```

However I'm having results that make no sense to me when comparing the two datetimes. Two DateTimes thar are the same time get compared to false. Here's some irb code:

```
(rdb:1) p self.published_at.to_i == self.expired_at.to_i
true
(rdb:1) p self.published_at.to_i == self.expired_at.to_i + 1
false
(rdb:1) p self.published_at == self.expired_at
false
(rdb:1) p self
#<Highlight id: nil, title: "MyString", published_at: "2011-06-02 10:22:05", expired_at: "2011-06-02 10:22:05", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, program_id: 827572094>
```

Anyone could enlighten me in how those comparisons work?

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate. You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472851/date-time-comparison-in-ruby

Comment: no the question is quite different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably **self.published_at.nsec** is not equal to **self.expired_at.nsec** . (nsec returns the nanoseconds). See the **[doc for <=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000342)**.